# Hosting Website to local in IIS

Tags: visual-studio, iis, web-hosting

I am able to host website in IIS 8 but not with ip add. The binding with ip and browsing the site in chrome gives 'ERR_NETWORK_ACCESS_DENIED' 
http://localhost   - works
http://10.111.148.133/ - does not work.

Comment: This is most likely your antivirus program blocking Chrome

Comment: @Alundra the dreamwalker Not even browse fro other PC or Phone

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are using your public IP.

You can browse using your local IP address. Your local IP address should be some thing like 192.168.xxx.xxx .

You can check your local Ip address  using the following command in command prompt.

```
ipconfig/all
```

if you want to access your site using public ip, then you need to  port forward from your public IP to localIp by setting the [DMZ Host](http://www.tp-link.in/article/?faqid=28) in your router.

Comment: You don't need the `/all` keyword. Especially to find out your IP address.

Comment: @AaronGillion the same PC/laptop can be connected to  multiple network say on Lan and on Wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the above answer, try going through your Firewall settings on the *host computer* and enabling anything related to IIS or port 80.

You can easily figure out if your antivirus or firewall is the issue by temporarily disabling it.

However, I think your issue is that you grabbed your public IP address, off whatsmyip.com or something, you just need to exec `ipconfig` to see what your *local* IP is.